# Is there a way to validate strings that represent nested object keys in Joi?

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I'm using joi@^17.4.0 and have a schema that looks like this:

```
settings: Joi.object({
  isHidden: Joi.boolean(),
  payoutData: Joi.object({
    email: Joi.string().email(),
  }),
}),
```

I would like to input the string `'settings.isHidden'` or `'settings.payoutData.email'` without hard coding each of these strings in the schema. Is there a way that I can make joi know that these strings are valid based on the object schema I already have? Currently, when I try to validate these strings I get a validation error that says those keys are not allowed.

Example object to validate:

```
{ 'settings.isHidden': false }
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible with Joi alone. Using a variant of your schema, you may need to implement your own validation function that utilises something like [`Hoek.reach()`](https://github.com/hapijs/hoek/blob/master/API.md#reachobj-chain-options) to extract the rules.

Comment: @Ankh Just what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your Joi schema:

```
settings: Joi.object({
  isHidden: Joi.boolean(),
  payoutData: Joi.object({
    email: Joi.string().email(),
  }),
}),
```

says that `settings` (presumably a property of an object) is an object that has two properties:

- `isHidden`, a boolean, and
- `payoutData`, an object with the property `email`, a string

Your example object

```
{ 'settings.isHidden': false }
```

is an object with a single property `settings.isHidden` and it so fails validation.

Ergo, your object fails validation against the schema.

Comment: I think OP understands why it's failing, their question is whether an object key chain can be used to reference a rule in the schema - which to my knowledge isn't possible with Joi natively.